# Conditionals in Ansible with dictionary

Tags: svn, ansible

I think I might misunderstand something in Ansible.

I want to build a role for subversion.

Here is my hosts-file:

```
[locaton1]
server-location1.domain.com

[location2]
server-location2.domain.com
```

I have a vars-file like this:

```
- repos_location1:
    repo1:
      reponame: project1
      repogrp: grp-project1
    repo2:
      reponame: project2
      repogrp: grp-project2
      subrepo:
        reponame: subproject2
        repogrp: grp-subproject2

- repos_location2:
    repo1:
      reponame: project3
      repogrp: grp-project3
    repo2:
      reponame: project4
      repogrp: grp-project4
```

Then, I have my task-file. This is just a snippet:

```
- name: Build configuration
  template: src=subversion.conf.j2 dest=/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf
  with_dict: ????
```

Now comes the clue: I want to have a when statement, like: "When the host is in [location1], use repos_location1, but use repos_location2, when in [location2].

I hope, you understand my point. Otherwise I would have to make a role svn-location1 and svn-location2.

Additional I want to have a statement in my template file, like this:

"If "subrepo" exists, do something"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be much better of using [group variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#group-variables) instead here.

Instead you define your variable as a generic `repos` and set it for each group so you have something like this:

#### group_vars/location1:

```
repos:
    repo1:
      reponame: project1
      repogrp: grp-project1
    repo2:
      reponame: project2
      repogrp: grp-project2
      subrepo:
        reponame: subproject2
        repogrp: grp-subproject2
```

#### group_vars/location2:

```
repos:
    repo1:
      reponame: project3
      repogrp: grp-project3
    repo2:
      reponame: project4
      repogrp: grp-project4
```

You can then use it like this:

```
- name: Build configuration
  template: src=subversion.conf.j2 dest=/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf
  with_dict: repos
```

I would, however, suggest that you change your new `repos` variable to be a list of dictionaries to allow you to more easily iterate through it and add/remove repos to the variable. So something like this instead:

```
repos:

    - reponame: project3
      repogrp: grp-project3

    - reponame: project4
      repogrp: grp-project4
```

You'd then iterate through `repos` with a [`with_items`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#standard-loops) iterator.